# Delphi XE2: How to draw transparent GIF images on toolbar using TImageList

Tags: delphi, transparency, toolbar, gif, timagelist

Using: Delphi XE2; VCL Forms application

Is it possible to draw transparent GIF images on an ActionToolbar (with ActionManager) using TImageList?

I have been trying but what I get is a black background on the toolbuttons.

The GIF images are 256 colors; and have transparency (verified by opening the images in Corel PaintShopPro).

On the ImageList, I have set the properties:

ColorDepth := cd32bit, 
DrawingStyle := dsTransparent.

Screen captures of the form at design-time and run-time:

[image]

[image]

Any tips or workaround is appreciated!

Comment: Isn't this the bottom-left-pixel thing? http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/timage_transp.htm  In that case the transparent color is defined differently (pixel vs. palette index), so you'll have to match those.

Comment: `cd32bit` is wrong, as is `dsTransparent`. There's no alpha channel here. FWIW, GIF is the wrong format for these images. You want 32bpp with alpha channel.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes. I have corrected to cd8Bit. But not sure about the alpha channel. Where is the property setting for that?

Comment: A GIF does not have an alpha channel. You should stop using GIF if you want to have good transparency.

Answer (score 1):

Save your GIF as PNG. The PNG has alpha channel and supports semi transparency

Comment: Starting from a GIF, there won't be any alpha since GIF is a 256 colour palette based format. Yes, PNG supports alpha, but there won't be partial transparency when converting GIF to PNG.